# C++ : template class specialization and type traits

Tags: c++, class, templates, specialization

My problem is the following

```
template<class T> MyClass
{
    MyClass(/* Lots of parameters with no problem */, const T& min = 0, const T& max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    set(/* Lots of parameters with no problem */, const T& min = 0, const T& max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
    /* Lots of function with no problem */
}
```

I want my template class to be compatible with `std::string` without reimplementing all the functions. For std::string I want `min = ""` and `max = ""`. Currently, it crashes as 0 for example cannot be converted to a string. How to do that ? (if I can specialize only the constructor and the main setter it would be great).

Comment: By compatible you mean: if `T == std::string` it should play nicely OR `MyClass` should be a drop-in replacement for `std::string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the wrapper I guess? :

```
template<typename T> struct ttraits
{
static T max(){
return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
}
static T min(){
return std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
}
};

template<> struct ttraits<std::string>
{
static std::string max(){
return ""; //or whatever max is for you
}
static std::string min(){
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always select the right overload for something to handle special cases with `enable_if` or you can think better about how to make your code more robust. Using `0` to initialize a template parameter is not a good idea, while `T()` is.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own `numeric_limits` that redirects to the standard ones and is specialized for string.

Comment: If you call it `default_max` or something, it will be easier.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
set(T & const p_Arg = Initializer<T>())
```

where `Initializer` is specialized for all supported types.